# Stop Ubuntu VM Stuttering

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8.1, virtual-machine

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 as a VMWare Workstation Virtual Machine inside Windows 8.1. Windows is the host, Ubuntu the guest.

As it stands, my Ubuntu VM keeps stuttering. Music keeps stuttering, but, even worse, typing is horrible. It freezes, I can't type for a few seconds and then my text splashes across the screen. Occasionally I get double letters, aand Ii sstart ttyping like this.

It's all because of this stuttering lag. Please someone tell me how to get rid of it. I just want to type in vim. And play music. I want to type and play music on a £600 laptop.

My laptops specs are as follows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OWiae.png]

My VM specs:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iR1Za.png]

As you can see these resources are not even being halfway used while the VM is running inside windows. These screenshots were taking during its stuttering performance:

ubuntu:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NzJLS.png]

windows:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ECzeK.png]

Windows is running smoothly. How do I stop ubuntu stuttering, please. I am running no applications in windows and have pruned my processes, but even so you can see 53% of my RAM is available, 99.999% disk IO is available and 94% of my processor is available...

In Ubuntu, 76% of my memory is free and 74% of my cpu is free. It's a mystery.

**Update: I have tested the VM in Workstation 10, Workstation 11 and VMWare Player Pro, and they all stutter. I really don't think it's the vmitself. No soft-lock ups, no errors reported...it's fine apart from the stuttering.**

Comment: Can't post images or more than 2 links until I have 10 rep.

Comment: Have you tried with other VM software? like Oracle's VritualBox? Do you have the VT-x virtualization enhacements enabled on the bios?

Comment: arielnmz I've paid for workstation (player served me well on my desktop that is no hundreds of miles away) but I have not enabled VT-x virtualization. I'll try that out :) what does it do and do you know why my resources are free and its lagging? (Even if VT-x virtualization is turned off?)

Comment: The suggestion to test a different virtualization software is to discard any issues with your current software, it may be a bug or something. And Intel's VT-x support is just an enhacement to better support virtualization on the machine. Also, have you tried with a different guest OS? I don't trust Ubuntu much :/. For the record, I'm currently running a Fedora 21 host with a WIndows 7 guest on a Celeron N2840 with 4 GB of RAM and both run pretty smoothly, so I wouldn't blame your hardware at all.

Comment: Don't get me wrong it was good shout to test out different software, it would just seriously suck. I'll use VT-x, thanks.

Comment: @arielnmz Still occurring with VT-x enabled. It's horrible.

Comment: Have you tried with a different virtualization software?

Comment: @arielnmz No, but I updated workstation to the latest version (it uninstalls the old version installs the new one cleanly) and the problem still persists. I guess I'll try Player and hope that works. If not, I'll use Virtual Box.

Comment: @JayTarka Have you installed VMWare Tools on the *Guest* OS? It can improve performance dramatically. How to: http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525

Comment: @misha256 Yep :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my own extensive experience virtualizing desktop OS, I can confidently tell you that Ubuntu doesn't virtualize nearly as well as *Windows* in general OR leaner Linux distros such as *Linux Mint Mate*.

On my end I generally use *Linux Mint Mate* as my go-to distro for running under VirtualBox or VMWare Workstation (I use both).

However, if you want to see how far you can get with Ubuntu, here's my advice:

- GUEST: Make sure you have installed [VMWare Tools](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1022525) in Ubuntu. This can improve performance dramatically.
- HOST: Do enable VT-x in your BIOS. But be aware that (ironically) VT-x doesn't improve Guest performance, or reduce host load, all that much.
- HOST: Make sure all Host drivers are up-to-date (especially the video driver).
- HOST: Configure your antivirus/antimalware software to EXCLUDE the folder in which your Guest files reside (including the hard drive image file).
- GUEST: Disable any unnecessary desktop enhancements, animations, and graphical silliness in the Guest (don't forget to try disable Compiz too).
- HOST: Install [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/) and test your Ubuntu Guest in that. Preferably make a backup of the Guest hard drive image file first. If you find VirtualBox works well, while VMWare doesn't, then at least that confirms your laptop is capable and something is not working right in VMWare.
- GUEST: Don't waste your resources on 64-bit Guests. In my experience, 32-bit Guests use less resources and run faster (sometimes significantly so) compared to 64-bit Guests.

Comment: Thanks, 3 versions of VMWare all stuttered, the free oracle software is running my imported VM beautifully